# How to print javascript function in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a separate A.js file with a function that prints a value. I also have a separate HTML file B.html. Is there a way to print the value from A.js to B.HTML? Right now I have this in my A.js:

```
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = totSum;
```

This in my B.HTML inside the body tag:
    `<script>
     <div id="sum"></div>
     </script>`

Comment: Why is HTML inside of a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the script after the declaration of the `sum` div.

**A.js**:

> document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = totSum;

**B.html**:

> `[...]<div id="sum"></div> <script src='A.js'></script>[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="sum"></div>


<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>

</body>
```

And of course, somewhere in the folder with your B.html file, you have a.js and b.js (or whatever you are calling them).

Make sure the function that is printing the sum is actually being called, and instead of having it return a value (or perhaps in addition to returning a value), have it change the value of the item on the page:

```
var sumView = document.getElementById("sum");
sumView.value = sumFunct(3,5);
```